# How to remove the word "homepage" in a WordPress page title?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have noticed that in my WordPress site my title contains the word "homepage".

How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is the name of your current page .just move to another page word home page will disappear .e.g
just move to about us page or blog page than it will be blog-"your site title"

Comment: https://parisairportdisneyprestigetransfer.com/ this is also my another site sir, i didnt get home page title, i have a more than 3 sites, i got this error only this site sir --> https://paris-airport-best-transfer.com/

Comment: for me its difficult to find our the reason through a link  but i am sure its not an error